# Binary search not run?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, search, data-structures

I tried to use binary search algorithm in my code example but It does not run as my expect. I dont know why. Please explain for me

```
var array = [1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 17, 19, 34, 55, 78, 80];

function binarySearch (array, numberToSearch) {
var firstIndex = 0;
var lastIndex = array.length - 1;
var currentIndex;
var currentElement;

currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 2;
currentElement = array[currentIndex];

while (firstIndex <= lastIndex) {
    if (numberToSearch === currentElement) {
        // found
        console.log(currentIndex);
        return currentIndex;
    } else if (numberToSearch < currentElement) {
        lastIndex = currentIndex - 1;
        currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 2;
        currentElement = array[currentIndex];
    } else if (numberToSearch > currentElement) {
        firstIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 2;
        currentElement = array[currentIndex];
    }
}
 return -1;
}
binarySearch(array, 12);
```

I should print: 5 but nothing happend

Comment: I guess, you meant Binary search not Binary sort ?

Comment: I think you are not allowing the loop to run completely using those return -1. I think you are mixing up an iterative solution with a recursive one.

Comment: @82Tuskers I return -1 for the no result condition. But I think it is not the problem

Comment: The `return -1` is not the only problem but it is the reason the `while` loop only does a single iteration.

Comment: @Thijs ok I recognized and I tried to remove it or place it out of the while loop. But the code still get the same result: nothing

Comment: @KeitaroUrashima Feel free for any queries.

Comment: Just swap the 2 lines: firstIndex = currentIndex + 1; and lastIndex = currentIndex - 1; and you are done.

Comment: @KeitaroUrashima Also why would you perform a bit wise OR, I dont understand that?

Comment: @SumeetSingh I am reading your answer, thank for your help. The "|" is used to round the number. Ex: 9/2=4.5, then using "|" the result will be 4

Comment: @KeitaroUrashima Then shouldnt you be doing it with a 0 instead of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with your code:

1. It should be `var currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 0;`
   (not `| 2`);
2. `currentIndex` and `currentElement` should be calculated at each
       iteration inside the loop.

So, this is the corrected version of your code:

```js
var array = [1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 17, 19, 34, 55, 78, 80];

function binarySearch (array, numberToSearch) {
var firstIndex = 0;
var lastIndex = array.length - 1;

while (firstIndex <= lastIndex) {
    var currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 0;
    var currentElement = array[currentIndex];
    if (numberToSearch === currentElement) {
        return currentIndex;
    } else if (numberToSearch < currentElement) {
        lastIndex = currentIndex - 1;
    } else if (numberToSearch > currentElement) {
        firstIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    }
}
 return -1;
}

console.log(binarySearch(array, 99)); // -1
console.log(binarySearch(array, 12)); // 5
```

BTW, this `var currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 0;` looks quite unusual. The common way is `var currentIndex = Math.floor((lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2);`

Comment: Although `var currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 0;` seems unfamiliar to you, it is the [most optimal](https://jsperf.com/jsfvsbitnot/8). You shouldn't discourage good practice.

Comment: I am sure you are right, but it is not very commonly used in such a context in JS - I mean it is not something that everybody knows and understands and optimization itself is barely perceptible. So, I prefer to use more clear things.

Comment: btw, once I have watched a video by Douglas Crockford where he warns people coming from C++ etc. that in JS bit operators have different cost and he doesn't recommend using them unless they are what you actually want to perform.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is the point of the bitwise `OR` here:

```
currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 2;
```

I think it should be:

```
currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2;
```

There is basic **flaw in search space update**.
When `numberToSearch < currentElement` means the `middle element`(*element at index currentIndex*) is greater than number to be searched, therefore, correct **new boundaries are**:

```
lastIndex = currentIndex - 1;
```

Also when `numberToSearch > currentElement` means the `middle element`(*element at index currentIndex*) is less than number to be searched, therefore, correct **new boundaries are**:

```
firstIndex = currentIndex + 1;
```

Therefore, the correct code is:

```
var array = [1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 17, 19, 34, 55, 78, 80];

function binarySearch (array, numberToSearch) {
var firstIndex = 0;
var lastIndex = array.length - 1;
var currentIndex;
var currentElement;

currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2;
currentElement = array[currentIndex];

while (firstIndex <= lastIndex) {
    if (numberToSearch === currentElement) {
        // found
        console.log(currentIndex);
        return currentIndex;
    } else if (numberToSearch < currentElement) {
        lastIndex = currentIndex - 1;
        currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 2;
        currentElement = array[currentIndex];
    } else if (numberToSearch > currentElement) {
        firstIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 2;
        currentElement = array[currentIndex];
    }
}
 return -1;
}
binarySearch(array, 12);
```

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake in the logic code :) . I edited it, but you know, still dont get the result. You can tried to run this code in your computer. The logic is true.

Comment: He was initially correct in  not using `Math.floor()`. The method he used [is sometimes faster](https://jsperf.com/jsfvsbitnot/8), but should be 0, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your corrected answer with all of the places I updated. You were pretty close! It seemed as though you were combining the [iterative](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2014/03/01/binary-search-in-javascript/) version of Binary Search with the [recursive](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-recursion-function-exercise-8.php) solution.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/floresfxf/pen/rzqWmq)

```
var array = [1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 17, 19, 34, 55, 78, 80];

function binarySearch (array, numberToSearch) {
  var firstIndex = 0;
  var lastIndex = array.length - 1;
  var currentIndex;
  var currentElement;

  while (firstIndex <= lastIndex) {
    currentIndex = (lastIndex + firstIndex) / 2 | 0; //should default to zero, not Two! 
    currentElement = array[currentIndex];//These should both update every iteration so it does not infinitely loop!
    if (numberToSearch === currentElement) {
      // found
      console.log(currentIndex);
      return currentIndex;
    }else if (numberToSearch < currentElement) {
      lastIndex = currentIndex - 1; //If current is too big, move right pointer to the left
    }else if (numberToSearch > currentElement) {
      firstIndex = currentIndex + 1;//If current is too small, move left pointer to the right
    }
  }
  return -1;//When condition of while it broken and no solution has been found, return -1 to indicate it is not in the array
}
binarySearch(array, 12) //5
```

It is further optimized by *not* using `Math.floor()` as `number | 0` [is sometimes faster.](https://jsperf.com/jsfvsbitnot/8)

Comment: Very clean!. Thank you for spending time for my problem :)